# Macro value not defined

Tags: c, macros, garbage

When we do not give the value in a macro substitution.

```
#define YES
printf("%d",YES)
```

The value of YES is not given, is it by default 0 or garbage?

Comment: Why not try compiling it and find out for yourself ?

Comment: @PaulR Because programming by experimentation with an implementation can't give a definitive answer. Maybe akash hopes someone quotes chapter and verse from a more authoritative document.

Comment: @Jens: that may be true in many cases, e.g. for undefined behaviour, but in this case the resulting compiler error would have answered the question decisively and deterministically.

Comment: @PaulR Not decisively. Coul be a compiler extension. Could be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just defined YES to **nothing**. So the result program after preprocessor should be `printf("%d",)`

Answer (score 2):

Neither, it has no value.

This usage is usually useful in situations like this:

```
#define _VXWORKS
```

Later, check if the macro has been defined.

```
#ifdef _VXWORKS
//do something
#else
//do something else
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised that it compiles

As the code hitting the compiler is

```
printf("%d",)
```

!!

Answer (score 2):

The C Preprocessor operates on ***tokens***. The macro definition for `YES` says to replace the token YES with no token, effectively removing the YES token. So, the result after macro replacement is

```
 printf ("%d",)
```

which is a syntax error as you observed.

Unlike uninitialized automatic variables, macro replacements are always well defined, so you cannot have indeterminate values ("garbage") as the result of macro expansion.

Comment: There was not a `;` in the post!

Answer (score 1):

nothing

you would use GCC : You can find to like this:
`gcc prog.c -E -P`